# (iphone) weird EXC_BAD_ACCESS , at A::A() in backtrace but code points to B::B()

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode4, exc-bad-access

In Xcode 4,

I'm having this weird EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
where backtrace shows 0 A::A() (in Debug navigator)
code is pointing at B::B() (in Editor view, A and B class doesn't share class hierarchy)

Both A & B are c++ struct.

I've tried cleaning the project.
(I suspect some object files didn't get cleaned up.
eager to know if there is a way to force-cleaning by removing build directory)

Thank you

Comment: do you have a minimal compilable example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: if I could come up with minimal example, I could have fixed it myself. but ya, trying to narrow it down where it's causing the problem is the way to go i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out it was
compiler being llvm-gcc

reverting back to gcc solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have released or autoreleased some unallocated member.